# Http запрос

Tags: python, django

В БД хранится адрес скрипта

https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id=45625252&v=5.26&fields=photo_100

которий видает

{"response":[{"id":45825644,"first_name":"Misha","last_name":"Misha","photo_100":"http:\/\/cs453645.vk.me\/v45364584\/9b10\/RjkjkjtSnPk.jpg","hidden":1}]}

Как передать в переменную

http://cs453645.vk.me/v45364584/9b10/RjkjkjtSnPk.jpg

???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в ответ приходит JSON. Его нужно распарсить.

```
import urllib
import json
raw_json = urllib.urlopen('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id=45625252&v=5.26&fields=photo_100').read()
data = json.loads(raw_json)
photo_100 = data['response'][0]['photo_100']
print photo_100
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то что мне нужно!

Answer (score 1):

Ну вопрос у Вас не очень понятный, тем не менее предложу вариант.
Если, например,

```
api_response = {"response":[{"id":45825644,"first_name":"Misha","last_name":"Misha","photo_100":"http:\/\/cs453645.vk.me\/v45364584\/9b10\/RjkjkjtSnPk.jpg","hidden":1}]}
```

то:

```
photo_url = api_response["response"][0]["photo_100"]
```